# iOS Reverse geocoding (getting the NAME of a location from its Coordinates, not just the address)

Tags: ios, mapkit, geocoding

I'm building a small little app for myself– right now, it has a function called performSearch that does a search within your local area of all nearby coffee places, gyms, and restaurants then drops pins at each of those locations. However, I'm confused as to how I can get the annotation to display the name of the location as shown on the actual map view. Anyone have any experience?

Basically, instead of displaying the address only, I want the annotation to say "Starbucks
Address…"

Sample code:

This does a search with any given Search field and drops pins on a map view of all locations in the given area with that search field.

```
var matchingItems: [MKMapItem] = [MKMapItem]()
@IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!

func performSearch(searchField: String) {

    matchingItems.removeAll()

    //search request
    let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchField
    request.region = self.map.region

    // process the request
    let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
    search.startWithCompletionHandler { response, error in
        guard let response = response else {
            print("There was an error searching for: \(request.naturalLanguageQuery) error: \(error)")
            return
        }

        for item in response.mapItems {
            // customize your annotations here, if you want
            var annotation = item.placemark
            self.reverseGeocoding(annotation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: allData.coordinate.longitude)

            self.map.addAnnotation(annotation)
            self.matchingItems.append(item)
        }

    }
}


func reverseGeocoding(latitude: CLLocationDegrees, longitude: CLLocationDegrees) {
    let location = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
            return
        }
        else if placemarks?.count > 0 {
            let pm = placemarks![0]
            let address = ABCreateStringWithAddressDictionary(pm.addressDictionary!, false)
            print("\n\(address)")
            if pm.areasOfInterest?.count > 0 {
                let areaOfInterest = pm.areasOfInterest?[0]
                print(areaOfInterest!)
            } else {
                print("No area of interest found.")
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `reverseGeocodeLocation` runs asynchronously, so you'd have to use completion handler pattern.

But, second, the reverse geocoding is unnecessary, as the `item` in the `response.mapItems` has a `name` property. So get use that as the title of your annotation.

For example:

```
func performSearch(searchField: String) {
    matchingItems.removeAll()

    //search request
    let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchField
    request.region = map.region

    // process the request
    let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
    search.startWithCompletionHandler { response, error in
        guard let response = response else {
            print("There was an error searching for: \(request.naturalLanguageQuery) error: \(error)")
            return
        }

        for item in response.mapItems {
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.title = item.name
            annotation.subtitle = item.placemark.title
            annotation.coordinate = item.placemark.coordinate
            self.map.addAnnotation(annotation)
            self.matchingItems.append(item)
        }
    }
}
```